# Can not get the right amount of people on my bus

Tags: java, class

```
package hw1;

public class CyrideBus {

    public static final int BUS_GARAGE = -1;
    private int currentCapacity;
    private int numStops;
    private int numPassengers;
    private int currentStop;
    private boolean inService;

 keeps track of bus stops
    public CyrideBus(int givenMaxCapacity, int givenNumStops) {
        currentCapacity = givenMaxCapacity;
        numStops = givenNumStops;
        currentStop = BUS_GARAGE;
        inService = true;
    }
    public int getCurrentCapacity() {
        return currentCapacity;

    }
    public int getCurrentStop() {
        return currentStop;
        
    }
    public int getNumPassengers() { 
        return numPassengers;
    }
    public int getTotalRiders() {
        
        return numPassengers + currentCapacity+ 1;
        

    }
    public boolean isInService() {

        return inService;

    }
    
    public void nextStop (int peopleOff, int peopleOn) {
        currentStop= (currentStop + 1)% numStops;
        peopleOff = Math.max(0, peopleOff);
        peopleOn = Math.max(0, peopleOn);
        numPassengers -= Math.min(peopleOff, numPassengers);
        int requiredCapacity = numPassengers + peopleOn;
        numPassengers = Math.min(requiredCapacity, currentCapacity);
         
        
    }
    public void placeInService() {
        inService = true;
        
    }
    public void removeFromService() {
        inService = false;
        
    }

}
```

trying to make a bus route program that keeps track of people on the bus at each stop. this bus route also has a bus garage. The number one issue I am having right now is that I can not get the right amount of people on my bus keep getting

for new bus with three stops, after nextStop() six times, current stop should be 2, expected 2 but was 5

for new bus with seven stops, fter nextStop() 137 times, current stop should be 3. expected 3 but was 136
and so on

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: And ask yourself, what do `numPassengers` and `currentCapacity` mean? Are they different? If so, does it make sense to add them together?

Comment: looking at the section in my code I can understand why adding numPassengers with CurrrentCapacity wouldn't really do much but hurt the code, but when I undo that code it actually loses me points, which furthers my confusion.

Comment: Debugging is an important skill to learn at this stage in your programming career. Even skilled professionals don't get the code right the first time and have to dig in to find out why. Read the article I linked in the first comment for some tips to get you startted.